# JavaScript namespacing - looking for a simple and efficient approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I would like to implement JavaScript Namespacing in a project. My co-workers and I are not specialists in JavaScript and therefore we are looking for a simple and efficient namespacing approach. Readability is a great asset, we are Java developers and easy preys for JavaScript traps.

We have written the following prove of concept:

```
<html><body><script>
var mynamespace = {};
mynamespace.variable = "inside mynamespace";
mynamespace.level1 = {};
mynamespace.level1.level2 = {};

(function(){
    this.variable = "inside mynamespace.level1";
    this.print = function(){ return "print() : " + this.variable };
}).apply(mynamespace.level1);

(function(){
    this.variable = "inside mynamespace.level1.level2";
    this.print = function(){ return "print() : " + this.variable };
}).apply(mynamespace.level1.level2);

// We can use "that" instead of "this"; however I do not see any benefit in doing it...
(function(){
    if(!mynamespace.level1.level2b){ this.level2b = {}; var that = this.level2b };
    that.variable = "inside mynamespace.level1.level2b";
    that.print = function(){ return "print() : " + this.variable };
}).apply(mynamespace.level1);

document.write(mynamespace.level1.print() + "<br>"); // print() : inside mynamespace.level1
document.write(mynamespace.level1.variable + "<br>");// inside mynamespace.level1

document.write(mynamespace.level1.level2.print() + "<br>");// print() : inside mynamespace.level1.level2
document.write(mynamespace.level1.level2.variable + "<br>");// inside mynamespace.level1.level2

document.write(mynamespace.level1.level2b.print() + "<br>");// print() : inside mynamespace.level1.level2b
document.write(mynamespace.level1.level2b.variable + "<br>");// inside mynamespace.level1.level2b

document.write(mynamespace.variable + "<br>");// inside mynamespace
document.write(mynamespace.something + "<br>");// undefined
</script></body></html>
```

=== Questions ===

Q1. Do you think that it is a good approach?

Q2. Is there any pitfall we could run into?

Q3. Would you have a better suggestion (please, consider simplicity, readability)?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers,

**EDIT:**
We are going to use jQuery. So, you there is a better approach using jQuery we would consider it.

Comment: read about requirejs instead of name-spacing everything

Comment: Your question is rather broad. You might find better responses by looking to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/ Here is an excellent resource for this. Please read further in to more design patterns in Javascript.

Comment: Since you are coming from Java - from this article "require.js can help organize javascript code into modules that behave in a way similar to packages in programming languages like java"...http://imediava.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/intro-require-js/

Comment: @CiananSims, essentially, I just want to know "yeah looks good" or "do not do it, you will run into problems". I did not know about Code Review, will take a look there. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @SujeshArukil, good article. In this article our approach is described as 5. Namespace injection. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @imrane, alright. I did not hear about requirejs, I am going to search more about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use JavaScript namespaces even for simple projects. I'm using following namespace pattern (found in JavaScript Patterns):

```
var SN = SN || {};

SN.namespace = function(ns_string) {
    var parts = ns_string.split('.'),
        parent = SN,
        i;

    // strip redundant leading global
    if(parts[0] === "SN") {
        parts = parts.slice(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        //create property if it doesn't exist
        if(typeof parent[parts[i]] === "undefined") {
            parent[parts[i]] = {};
        }

        parent = parent[parts[i]];
    }

    return parent;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
SN.namespace('SN.subnamespace1.subnamespace3');
SN.subnamespace1.subnamespace3.object = function() {};
```

It's good approach to create namespaces in this way when working in team - nobody will overwrite your namespace. Also you can easily specify one place (file) when team will create namespaces so it will be easy to see what name is taken or not.

Then I'm using closures to separate private context of objects if needed (as you have in your example as well). Closures are probably the most powerful tool in JS (functional programming). You can create contexts which persist until deletion of every inner object.

I also like [getInstance JavaScript pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674109/571230) and revelation pattern (it works with `new` and without as well):

```
var cat = function(name, color, size) {
    var _color = color,
        _size = size,
        _name = name,
        getName = function() { return _name; },
        getColor = function() { return _color; },
        getSize = function() { return _size; };
    return {
        color: getColor,
        size: getSize,
        name: getName
    }
};

var new_cat1 = new cat('a', 'b', 1);
var new_cat2 = new cat('c', 'd', 2);
var new_cat3 = cat('e', 'f', 3);

console.log(new_cat1.name());
console.log(new_cat2.name());
console.log(new_cat3.name());
```

Also read the book I mentioned on the beginning - personally I think it's best source of good practices when programming in JS. I learnt a lot from this book!

Comment: thank you very much. I will definitely give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I hope it will help - moving from Java is not easy, but will be fun for sure.

Comment: there is just one thing that still unclear for me. Let's suppose I create a namespace using [ SN.namespace('SN.cat'); ], next create a cat function [ var cat = function (... ]. How do I link the function to the namespace? Are you suggesting something like [ SN.cat = cat; ]?

Comment: I'm using namespaces as containers for properties and methods. So I would create namespace `SN.container` and then, inside this namespace (in separate file `sn.container.js`) I would do sth like this: `SN.container.cat = function() { ... }`. If you have any other questions - shoot it;)

Comment: I edited my code as well, as this line was a little bit misleading: `SN.namespace('SN.subnamespace1.subnamespace3.object');`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you are doing quite a good job already, just some small things needed to be improved. First, you should move your namespace to a separate file rather than put it in the same file with your work like this. I would recommend you put it in `namespace.js`. Next, the is quite very important as well, you should check whether the current namespace exist or not. Your code above always declares new variable. This is quite a serious problem especially when your colleague has already declared the namespace and put some properties to that namespace, your code will completely override your colleague, and you will always get error when you pull your colleagues' code. I would suggest:

In `namespace.js`:

```
var window.MyNameSpace = window.MyNameSpace || {};
MyNameSpace.variable = "inside mynamespace";
MyNameSpace.level1 = MyNameSpace.level1 || {};
MyNameSpace.level1.level2 = MyNameSpace.level1.level2 || {};
```

So when you colleagues have already declare the namespace or add some properties to the existing namespace, it won't override the existing one. Let's say your colleagues have already create `MyNameSpace` and added `MyNameSpace.level1 = something`. The code above won't override `MyNameSpace` and `MyNameSpace.level1`, it just point to current existing namespace and its properties.

**Note** You have to include the namespace.js before other js file, or you will get `undefined` error.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer it helped a lot. Tomorrow I am going to test a few things based in your answer... In your opinion, would you consider using requireJS instead for namespacing? (keep in mind we are going to use jQuery in our project)

Comment: I think you don't need to use requireJS in this case since it is just about creating namespace, not a complex js structure with many dependencies loaded. Also no need to add more 16kb to you page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few quick problems I can see.

Consider this:

```
var car = {};
car.manufacturer = "Toyota";
car.doors = 4;
car.format = "sedan";
car.wheels = 4;
```

There's a lot of repetition going on, here.
If you were to try making this a further-nested object, but continue defining properties this way, that would be a LOT of either retyping or copy/pasting.

```
var garage = {};
garage.cars = [];
garage.cars[0] = {};
garage.cars[0].doors = 4;
garage.cars[0].drivers = [];
garage.cars[0].drivers[0].name = "Bob";
```

...et cetera.

The first issue here is that it would become pretty easy to miss out on details, in one form or another.  There are so many lines, and so much repetition that perhaps on line 37, you forget to initialize `cars[3].drivers[1].license_number`.

The second issue is that if you break up this initialization, but attempt to initialize in an order which is poorly-defined (ie: doing this over multiple JS files, or doing it over multiple AJAX calls), then you run the risk of hitting an exception, when you try to add a property to a member which doesn't yet exist.

// core js
var MyApp = {};
MyApp.modules = {};

// js #2 loaded before js #1
MyApp.modules.myModule.subModule = {}; // will throw an exception

// js #1
MyApp.modules.myModule = {};

There are ways of getting around this, but they all depend on what you're hoping to achieve:

If you are looking at building data-structures which have static default values, then I'd suggest building a simple data-structure like this:

```
var car = {
    doors : 4,
    manufacturer : "Toyota"
};
```

Or a more elaborate object like this:

```
var garage = {
    cars : [
        {
            doors : 2,
            drivers : [
                { name : "Bob", age : 32 },
                { name : "Susanne", age : 18 }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

They can still easily be referenced like so:

```
garage.cars[0].drivers[1].name; // Susanne
```

If you are building modules of functionality, like a library, then namespacing is still a good idea.
Do so in either way presented in the other answers.

systematically-checking:

```
if (MyApp && MyApp.modules.myModule) {
    MyApp.modules.myModule.subModule = {
        send : function () { }
    };
}
```

Or building a function which you can use like:

```
namespace("MyApp.modules.myModule.subModule.addOn", { method : function () {},
                                                      property_1 : 1,
                                                      property_2 : false       });
```

Which could then split the string and check if each name existed, and create them if they don't.

Also, don't use `document.write`.  Browsers now do a good job of preventing it from screwing up sites, but you should use `console.log` for logging purposes, or DOM-manipulation (or `.innerHTML`, if need be) for writing to the page.

Also `that` doesn't really do what you think it might.
The problem with `this` is if you have a function inside of another function, `this` will become `window`, instead of staying the same as before.

An example:

```
function decrease_fuel () { this.fuel -= 1; }

var car = {
    fuel : 100,
    speed : 10,
    pos  : { long : ..., lat : ... },
    dir  : { long : ..., lat : ... },
    drive : function () {
        if (this.fuel > 0) {
            this.pos.long += this.dir.long * this.speed;
            this.pos.lat  += this.dir.lat  * this.speed;
            decrease_fuel(); // whoops! `this === window`
            // decrease_fuel.call(this); would work
        }
    }
};
```

So if you were to create a function where you wanted the inner-scope to point to the same `this` as the outer, you would use a variable which saves the value of the outer `this`, for the inner to reference through closure.

```
var outer = function () {
    var that = this,
        inner = function () { console.log(that); };
    inner();
};

outer.call({ name : "Bob" }); // logs bob object
```

If the line in `inner` was `console.log(this);`, then:

```
outer.call({ name : "Bob" }); // would log `window` object
```

As for `namespacing` versus `requireJS`, they're both the same thing, in a way.
Where they differ is in what they're used for.
`requireJS` is meant to be used to load multiple files, and to ensure that they're loaded in the right order.  And if you define namespaces, using requireJS, then they will be namespaced, when the loading is done.

With a simple namespace function, it would be up to you to load individual components, in the way your project agreed on, and then in each file, use the namespacing function to add each module.

If you only plan on having one JS file, then requireJS doesn't offer much benefit over the other.
If you're going to have multiple JS files (one per module, in the same way you might break out classes in Java), then `requireJS` offers benefits, at the cost of requiring you to learn the interface.